# Is Covid-19 still a problem/should it be considered one?

Tags: covid-19

I'm hearing different things from different people (as is always the case), about the current status of Covid-19.

Is the pandemic (endemic?) still an issue that's worse than influenza or other common illnesses?
Follow-up: Are measures to limit the spread of Covid-19 still justified?

Why are there currently so few Covid-19 cases and/or deaths even though the vaccination rate hasn't changed much since mid-2022?

What is the current vaccine data like? How much does vaccination decrease Covid-19 danger? How much does it limit spread?

I hope these questions make sense, please ask for clarification if they are not clear enough.

Thanks for everyone's help in advance!
Ladan

Comment: There are four questions here. Please [edit] your post to focus on a single question. (You can ask the others as separate questions.) Also, this site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, particularly when you make assertions of fact such as "Why are there currently so few Covid-19 cases and/or deaths". Who says that's true?

Comment: "I'm hearing different things from different people..." People are often unaware of scientific facts. Your country should have a health service website or even an infectious disease website (e.g. in the US, the CDC informs the public and health care providers.) That would be a better source of information.

Comment: Answering the title only. Yes, it is still a problem, but not world-wide anymore. e.g. I'm pretty sure in the USA it's not really a problem anymore, however read recently that India got new variants that cause them lots of problems. (If you'll edit to focus only on that, I can post this as answer)